# Items movement daily collection database design system issue

Tags: python, mysql

I am doing a very simple database in mysql to track movement of items. The current paper form looks like this:

```
Date     totalFromPreviousDay  NewToday   LeftToday  RemainAtEndOfDay
1.1.2017    5                     5           2          8 (5+5-2)
2.1.2017    8                     3           0         11  ( 8+ 3 -0)
3.1.2017    11                    0           5         6   (11+0-5)
```

And so forth. In my table, I want to make totalFromPreviousDay and RemainAtEndOfDay calculated fields which I show in my front end only. That is mainly cos we tend to erase on the paper due to errors. I want them to be reflected based on changes to the other two fields. As such, I did my table like this:

```
id
date
NewToday
LeftToday
```

Now the problem I am facing is, I want to select any date and be able to say "there were 5 items at the start of the day or from previous day, then 5 were added, 0 left and the day ended with 10 items"

So far, I can't really think of a way going about it. Theoretically, I want to try something like this: if the requested day is Feb. 1, 2017, start at 0 cos that's the day we started collecting data. If not, loop thru the records at 0 and doing the math until the requested date is found.

But that is obviously inefficient cos i have to start form first date until the last every time.

Is my approach ok or I should include the columns in the table? If the first, what would be the way to do it in python/mysql?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to step back a little bit and define the business needs first (it is worthwhile to talk somebody, who worked with stocks before) because these determine your table structure.

A system always tracks the current level of stocks and the movement. It is a business decision how often you save your historical stock level and this influences how you store the data.

You may save the current stock level along with all transactions. In this case you would store the stock level in the transactions table. You do not even have to sum up a transactions per day because the last transaction per day will have the daily closing stock level anyway.

You may choose to save the historic stock levels regularly (on a daily / weekly / monthly, etc. basis). In this case you will have a separate historic stock levels table with stock id, stock name (name may change over the time, so may be a good idea to save it), date and the level. If you would like to know the historic stock level for any point of time that falls between your saved points, then you need to take the latest saved stock level before the period you are looking for, and sum up all transactions to the saved period.

Comment: @Shadow....thanks. Actually, there is ONLY kind of item so there is no reason to create an items table. What we want is basically how many items were there at the start of a month (hence, the last remaining item count from the last day of the previous month) and how many items remained at the end of the month (last day).

Comment: Well, I described you a version that works for this.